# ESP32 Baud Rate

Tags: arduino, nfc, arduino-esp32, baud-rate

I'm currently utilizing an ESP32-Wroom-32 board in conjunction with a PN5180 to read tags. Through my research, I've discovered that the default baud rate for communication is 115200. Could increasing the baud rate beyond the default value affect the performance of the board, particularly in the context of reading tags with the PN5180?

Additionally, are there any considerations or limitations I should be aware of before making such adjustments? I have also encountered information suggesting that cable length could potentially impact performance depending on the chosen baud rate. Given that the cable I'm using is 5 meters long, is this true in this scenario?

Not sure if this has any impact but I'm using CH340 drivers to facilitate the serial communication.

Comment: there is no default baud rate for the ESP32. are you talking about communication of ESP32 with the PN5180? why do you mention then CH340 then?

Comment: PN5180 require an SPI interface for communicating with a host MCU, what does that has anything to do with UART baud rate?